# Cannot resolve symbol DefaultBatchConfigurer- Spring boot 3

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

We are migrating to spring boot 3V from 2.7V , one of our BatchConfig class extends the DefaultBatchConfigurer class from the package org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.DeafultBatchConfigurer throws error  "Cannot resolve symbol DefaultBatchConfigurer". This class is needed for us to override the  method setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) in the batchconfiguration implementation class to prevent the compiler from returning SQL exception that is caused by creating a job.

```
public class BatchConfiguration extends DefaultBatchConfigurer {

@override
public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource){
}
```

Please tell on how to handle this issue.

Comment: Did you copy that fully qualified class name from your import statement? Did you notice that it contains a misspelling ("Default", not "Deafult") as you typed it. Check your spelling and let us know whether you made a typo.

Comment: spring boot 3 version removed the DefaultBatchConfigurer and replaced with DefaultBatchConfiguration. Able to use the new one . Thanks all.